# How would I push update to github fork after branched issue is complete in gitlabhq?

Tags: git, github, prestashop

So the origin is our fork. The upstream is prestashop. My gitlabhq project contains the mirror of our github fork.

I need to setup hooks after an issue is resolved in such a way that we can request merge back to the prestashop project.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Are you just asking how to push the changes in your fork to the upstream repo? Or are you asking how to update your local fork with your remote fork and/or the original repo?

Comment: 1. Fork upstream in github
2. clone to gitlab
3, Fire off a push to forked repo on github after new issue/feature is done.

Comment: What do you consider a done issue/feature ? isn't that simple push?

Comment: Any gitlab issue/feature that has been QA and ready to push to origin for merge consideration with prestashop project. @bitou